# how to serve webp from a variable in a static tag wagtail 2.5

Tags: python, django, templates, wagtail

I made a carousel orderable. each instance has an image and char field for the webp file name through the picture element. The webp image loads perfect when I hard code the srcset instead of using a {{variable}}.

Problem is that keeps the admin backend from being dynamic and leaves me hard coding every pic on the site or just the pages I want to rank for on google. Ive read a bunch of other posts but im still stuck. is there any way to serve webp filename cleanly from the backend?

I have read.

[load static file with variable name in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040941/load-static-file-with-variable-name-in-django)

[django 1.5 - How to use variables inside static tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag)

This one was the closest to solving my problem but falls short.

https://snakeycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/20/variables-in-django-static-tags/

## carousel orderable fields

```
carousel_image = models.ForeignKey("wagtailimages.Image",       on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name="+",) 
webp = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

## home template carousel

```
{% for loop_cycle in self.carousel_images.all %}
{% image loop_cycle.carousel_image max-750x500 as img %}

<picture>
<source srcset="{% static '{{loop_cycle.webp}}'%}" type="image/webp" >
<img src="{% static '{{img.url}}'%}" alt="{{ img.alt }}">
</picture>
```

As this works perfect when I hard code but then whats the point of having a carousel with an orderable that is next-gen image friendly? Thank you for reading Im going CRAZY?

```
<picture>
<source srcset="{% static '{{loop_cycle.webp}}'%}" type="image/webp" >
<img src="{% static '{{img.url}}'%}" alt="{{ img.alt }}">
</picture>
```

As this works perfect when I hard code but then whats the point of having a carousel with an orderable that is next-gen image friendly? Thank you for reading Im going CRAZY?

Answer (score 0):

ok so did some fiddleing and figured it out here is the working code.

```
<picture>
<source srcset="{% static 'webp/'|add:loop_cycle.webp|add:'.webp' %}" type="image/webp" >

<img src="{% static 'webp/'|add:loop_cycle.webp|add:'.webp' %}" alt="{{ img.alt }}">
</picture>
```

im sooooo happy!!!!