# Image for loop in Django template html

Tags: django, image, loops, for-loop, static

I would like to ask how to generate images in for loop in html template in Django:

this code doesn't work:

```
<ul>
    Plants:
    {% for plant in plants %}
        <li> <img src="{% static 'plant_photos/{{ plant.name }}.jpg' %}"> {{ plant.name }}</li>

    {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

but if I replace this: {{ plant.name }}.jpg by this: carrot.jpg then the image is displayed.

All the images I have saved in static/plant_photos and the name of each photo correspond with name of the plant.

models.py:

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    plant_image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='static/plant_photos/', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=20)


class Garden(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    plant = models.ManyToManyField(Plant, related_name="gardens", through="GardenPlant")
```

views.py:

```
def garden_detail(request, garden_name): 
garden_id = Garden.objects.get(name=garden_name).id 
   garden = Garden.objects.get(id=garden_id) 
   plants = Plant.objects.filter(gardens__name=garden_name) 
   context = { 
       'name': garden.name, 
       'description': garden.description, 
       'address': garden.address, 
       'plants': plants, } 
   return render(request, 'garden_detail.html', context=context)
```

structure:

```
garden_app
_templates
_static
__plant_photos
___carrot.jpg
___apple.jpg
___pear.jpg
```

...

Comment: please add you html, view , model, code too

Comment: add in you question not in comment section

Comment: with edit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the interest is very limited but to achieve your goal, you can pass a full string to the static tag from `staticfiles` like this :

Don't use `{% static ... %}`, try this instead :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<ul> Plants:
{% for plant in plants %}
  {% with 'plant_photos/'|add:plant.name|add:'.jpg' as plant_photo %}

    <li><img src="{% static plant_photo %}">{{ plant.name }}</li>

  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %} </ul>
```

For more information, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040941/load-static-file-with-variable-name-in-django/31593102) can help.

Comment: it is working....many many thanks

Comment: Mark the questions as it's resolve your issue ;-)