# How add object variable in static block django?

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I implement addition object variable in static block, for example:

```
<script src="{% static 'base/js/{{obj.id}}_container.js' %}"></script>
```

How to make it works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [load static file with variable name in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040941/load-static-file-with-variable-name-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
{%with obj.id|slugify as id%}
```

`<script src="{% static 'base/js/'|add:id|add:'_container.js'%}"></script>`

and it works.