# The variable template tag is not 'seen' by django when trying to load static images dynamically

Tags: django-templates, loading-image, ihtmlimgelement

I am using Django backend for my project. I have a folder of images(3,700) in my static directory. I want to pass them to the front-end HTML file in a dynamic way using the `img` tag. The names of my images are numeric and are linked to a dictionary I have made. Here is an example of the dictionary:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "moldb_iupac": "2-Ketobutyric acid",
    "description": "the description",
    "smiles": "CCC(=O)C(O)=O",
    "name": "2-Ketobutyric acid"
  }
```

When I loop over it using a for loop I extract the necessary `key:value` pairs and I am able to insert them into a HTML using the `{{ my_dict_entry['name'}}` for example. The problem occurs when I try to concatenate the `src` of an image tag using help from this [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040941/load-static-file-with-variable-name-in-django). I don't know how to do it any other way to be honest.

So in my HTML I have this:

```
{% for  item in matches %}
        
    <div class = "match">
        <img src="{% static 'images/'%}{{item.id}}.png" alt="Image of the match">
        <li>Name is: {{ item.name}}</li>
        <p>{{ item.description}}</p>
        <p>The smile for this match is: {{ item.smiles}}</p>
    </div> 
    {%endfor%}
</body>
</html>
```

Then my Kernel responds with this outcome:

```
[12/Nov/2023 22:57:40] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14381
[12/Nov/2023 22:57:40] "GET /static/images/.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1792
```

So from this, you can see that the computer doesn't seem to see the `{{item.id}}` at all.
The page loads fine with text but there is no images. However, if I change the `{{item.id}}` for `0` for example. The image "0.png" appears and the kernel says this:

```
[12/Nov/2023 23:02:26] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14398
[12/Nov/2023 23:02:26] "GET /static/images/0.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6997
```

I am doing this on a windows machine, but so far everything works fine with my Django project. All files are connected and the directories work.

Please help thou.